# How to use pyttsx in a python thread

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I am working with `pyttsx3` for text-to-speech. I realized that I can use it within a thread (or I am doing something wrong). Do you know why?

Code Example:

```
from threading import Thread
import pyttsx3

def myfunc():
  engine = pyttsx3.init()
  engine.say("ok")
  engine.runAndWait()

t = Thread(target=myfunc)
t.start()
```

Error:

```
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 9, in myfunc
    engine.runAndWait() #blocks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 188, in runAndWait
    self.proxy.runAndWait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 204, in runAndWait
    self._driver.startLoop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 33, in startLoop
    AppHelper.runConsoleEventLoop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.py", line 241, in runConsoleEventLoop
    nextfire = nextfire.earlierDate_(soon)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'earlierDate_'
```

Comment: Have you been able to run pyttsx3 without thread? The code that you sample runs correctly for me.

Comment: @eyllanesc Really? Yes of course without thread pyttsx3 works fine

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's OS-based: mine doesn't work, and the OP and I are both using Macs (I assume because those look like homebrew paths).

Comment: @rassar Yes I am using Mac and Homebrew...

Comment: Can you suggest any other multi platform tts?

Comment: have you looked into [this](https://github.com/originell/jpype/issues/256)? Your error is in pyObjCTools, not in pyttsx3 directly. And that guy has the same error as you have

Comment: Thank you! Interesting but he doesn't seem to resolve his problem...

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be that it doesn't run in threads on osx. Here are some examples that might work well:

If you just need to convert text into speech, you can use `os.system('say %s')`:

```
import os
def myfunc():
  os.system('say ok')
```

[gTTS](https://github.com/desbma/GoogleSpeech) or Google's TextToSpeech engine, supports 64 languages, including italian. Usage:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
tts = gTTS(text='Good morning', lang='it')
tts.save("good.mp3")
os.system("mpg321 good.mp3")
```

Comment: Thank you, but it needs to be cross-platform and must support Italian language.

Comment: I'd like it to be offline. Sorry ;)

Comment: So an offline, cross-platform, multilingual text-to-speech engine? Unfortunately, `pyttsx` is probably your best bet. You could try submitting a GitHub issue and see where that gets you -- https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/new

Comment: Already done! Lets see what happens, for now I am going to use gTTS. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think pyttsx3 can't make a sound in multiple threads (it's OK to make a sound only once). If you want to make a sound in multiple threads, the Macos system should use the say command.

Other operating systems should also have corresponding commands

```py
import sys
import os
import threading

print('threading1:',threading.activeCount())
text = 'Please start'

def myfunc():
    while True:
        # os.system('say another')
        # os.system('say -v Daniel "another"')
        # os.system('say -v Daniel "[[rate 160]] another"')  # 速度默认200
        os.system('say -v Daniel -r 140 "{}"'.format(text))
        os.system('say -v Samantha -r 140 "{}"'.format(text))
        # print(111)

loopThread = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, name='backgroundMusicThread')
loopThread.daemon = True
loopThread.start()

print('threading2:',threading.activeCount())

while True:
    text = input('input:\n')
    if text == 'end':
        sys.exit()
```